# how to sample a certain sound on a song?

Tags: recording

I would like to find out one of the best approaches on how to sample a certain sound  in a song? Open-source/freeware software would be ideal but propriety software is welcomed as well. I'm looking to use these samples in live  DJ performances and not music production. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to separate out a single sound from within a performance, you will need to use filters to try and remove frequencies higher and lower than those in the piece you want, but you will still be left with some noises.

If you can find the sound you want in a part of the song with no other instruments playing, this will be your best bet. Them just record it into your sampler.

Answer (score 0):

Recycle propeller heads is a good software that you can use to sample sounds. It allows you to cut audio according to different criteria such as bars, or you can place your own markers etc. unfortunately it is not free.

Ableton Live is also quite good to deal with sampling.

If you are looking for a free editor, there is none that comes to my mind now except audacity.

What are you using to launch your samples? A MPC, MPD, Maschine...?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of software, generally:

Programs for processing sound itself
Programs for putting sounds to good use

Nowadays, you can process digital sound in realtime. That means that DJing software could be used as both.

There is opensource DJing software such as Mixxx, and you should definitely checkout the demo version of Native Instruments' Traktor, which runs full for 30 minutes. There is also Virtual DJ, and others.

They all allow you to combine arbitrary samples with music tracks, without having to worry about timing and synchronization.